# how to subtract algebraic equations using column method?

Tags: equations

[image]
How to subtract the algebraic equations using column method? Also is any possibility to solve algebraic equations using latex?
Help to produce result like this latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is customary when asking a question to demonstrate a legitimate attempt at solving it yourself. You should include this attempt as a "Minimal Working Example" (MWE) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Your MWE should compile without errors even if it doesn't produce the exact result you desire. Then other users will be much more likely to help you toward a satisfactory solution.

Comment: LaTeX and TeX are designed primarily for *typesetting*, including the typesetting of math material. To solve symbolic algebraic expressions (including equations), you should look into software such as Mathematica and Maple.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer addresses only the question about how to typeset some linear equations.)

I suggest you employ an `array` environment. The following code illustrates most of the relevant techniques. You are obviously free to come up with more-descriptive labels than `(A)` and `(B)`; if you wish, you can also omit them entirely. Same for the `\cancel` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}     % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\usepackage{booktabs}  % for "\midrule" macro
\usepackage{cancel}    % for "\cancel" macro (optional)

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{R@{\quad}RCRCL}
(\mathrm{A}) 
& (\cancel{-28\lambda^3} +11\lambda^2 +\cancel{2\lambda} -1) a_2^2 
& + & (4\lambda^2 +2) a_3 
& = & B_1b_2+B_2b_1^2 \\
(\mathrm{B}) 
& (\cancel{-28\lambda^3} +19\lambda^2 +\cancel{2\lambda} +3) a_2^2 
& - & (4\lambda^2+2) a_3 
& = & B_1c_2+B_2c_1^2 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
(\mathrm{A})-(\mathrm{B})
& (-8\lambda^2-4)a_2^2 
& + & (8\lambda^2 +4) a_3 
& = & B_1(b_2-c_2)+B_2(b_1^2-c_1^2)\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I need one more help. When I try to draw a line down to the (A)- (B) row. I used \cline \hline also I used \cmidrule{2-6} but all these things aren't work correctly. Help me to complete that. Also I want to display the sign changes under the (B) row that shown in image which I post.

Comment: @SubramaniFalthoozMsm - Please be more specific than "all these things aren't work correctly". Separately, if you use `\cmidrule`, you should under no circumstance be using `\cline` and `\hline`, unless you want to generate awful output. Please clarify what it is you're trying to achieve. Finally, the reason my answer doesn't feature a row with `-` and `+` symbols is that I couldn't parse your handwritten notes. What exactly is supposed to be going on?

Comment: I need two things. 1. While subtracting algebraic expressions we have to change the sign. So that sign I need to display. 2. While we adding number at the end we draw 2 lines here only one line I need to draw one more line under the result

Comment: @SubramaniFalthoozMsm - I'm afraid I don't understand what you wrote regarding item 1. For item 2, write `\bottomrule` to draw a line under the entire expression.